# python wrong date incrementing

Tags: python, web-scraping

i have a problem. I webscraping stock website. I've got a problem, when i incrementing the date. When i'm incrementing from 1.1.2012 to 31.12.2012, the incrementing goes well to 31.9.2012, but from 1.10 to 31.12 it is wrong. Here is the code:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.date(2012,1,1)
for x in range(1,365):
    if d.day<10:
        dan = "0"+str(d.day)
    else:
        dan = d.day

    if d.month<10:
        mesec = "0"+str(d.month)
    else:
        month = str(d.month)
    leto= d.year

    print("http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1="+str(dan)+"."+str(mesec)+"."+str(leto))
    print(str(d.day)+str(d.month)+str(d.year))
    d = d + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

and output for 29.12.2012 is 29.09.2012, but the desired output is 29.12.2012:

http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=**29.09.2012**

Desired output:
**29.12.2012**

Comment: You assigned to `mesec` when `d.month` < 10 and `month` when `d.month` >= 10, and your string construction uses `mesec` which is neveer incremented past that point.

Comment: Wow yeah my fault :) thanks for solution!

Answer (score 1):

Manually formatting dates is error prone - you changed the name of your variables - `month` is never used to create the URI and `mesec` stays at 10 because it is never reassigned for `d.month > 9`. Seee @metatoaster's comment.

Instead of manually formatting, use [strftime - date formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
import datetime
d = datetime.date(2012,1,1)

# avoid off-by-1 leap-year mishaps due to hardcoded days/year
while d.year < 2013:   
    # format as dd.mm.yyyy including leading 0 if need be
    dd = d.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    print("http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1="+dd)

    d = d + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Output (for `d = d + datetime.timedelta(days=36)` to reduce output):

```
http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=01.01.2012
http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=06.02.2012
http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=13.03.2012
http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=18.04.2012
http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=24.05.2012
http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=29.06.2012
http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=04.08.2012
http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=09.09.2012
http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=15.10.2012
http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=20.11.2012
http://www.ljse.si/cgi-bin/jve.cgi?doc=2561&subtab=0_2&date1=26.12.2012
```